# How to make javascript Date.parse understand short years?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I noticed `Date.Parse` can't handle only 2 digits dates.

Say I have this

```
mm/dd/yy = 7/11/20
```

Date parse will think it is `= 7/11/1920`. Can you set it to use the year two thousand? Like it's kinda weird I got the jquery u.i date picker and if you type in `7/11/20` it will figure out `2020`.

So it would be nice if `Date.parse` could keep up I rather have them both not know what is going on or both know what is going on then have one that knows and one that does not know.

Comment: The best solution would be to provide the full date, always.

Comment: @BurnoLM I agree that's why I have a datepicker popup when the textbox is clicked however a user still can for some reason manually type in what I did "7/11/20" for whatever reason. It does not effect any of my C# code as it figures out that it is 2020 but it screws some of my dropdown lists that get filtered based on the date. So if I can fix it I would like too also for whatever reason jquery validate "date" does not think it is a validation error and is in a valid format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. But you can always adjust the year:

```
YourDate="7/11/20";
DateObj=new Date(YourDate.replace(/(\d\d)$/,"20$1"));

alert(DateObj);
```

[This code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/4p6d2/)

**Edit:** The following code will handle both full and short years:

```
YourDate="7/11/2020";
DateObj=new Date(YourDate.replace(/\/(\d\d)$/,"/20$1"));

alert(DateObj);
```

[This code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/bV7bA/)

Comment: What is this doing? I am kinda confused with $1 also the user could always give a full date. Then this fails. So how could it be modified?

Comment: the problem with this approach is if they type, say, 7/11/98, the date will be 7/11/2098, which is probably not what they meant, unless the dates they're entering are always supposed to be in the future in your particular situation. There needs to be a cutoff somewhere for two digit dates to work... where the cutoff is is arbitrary, but somewhere around 50 might make sense... But really, not accepting two-digit dates at all would be the best idea I think. :)

Comment: @chobo2 - The `$1` inserts the value that was found in the regex (the `(\d\d)` portion, which is two digits).

Comment: @chobo2 - There's no default. `\/(\d\d)` tries to match `/dd`, where `d` is a digit. If there's a match, it will replace the match with `/20dd`, if not, which is the case with for instance `/2015`, there will not be a replace.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is whether you can change the way Date.parse works so that low-numbered two-digit dates are interpreted as dates after the year 2000?

Yes, it can be done, simply shadow Date.parse with your own parse function.

```
// don't do this!
Date.parse = function (str) { /* your parse routine here */ }
```

Of course, it's generally a very bad idea to shadow properties (including 'methods' aka function properties) of host objects, because it will cause incorrect behavior in other scripts that expect those properties to work a certain way.

It's also a bad idea to use two digit dates, but that might be beyond your control. If it's not beyond your control, I'd advise to just forget 2-digit dates and use the full year value instead.

Comment: Just to enforce: this is very, very dangerous!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function parseDate(stringValue)
{
    var date = new Date(stringValue);
    if (!isNaN(date.getTime()))
    {
        // if they typed the year in full then the parsed date will have the correct year, 
        // if they only typed 2 digits, add 100 years to it so that it gets translated to this century
        if (stringValue.indexOf(date.getFullYear()) == -1)
        {
            date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 100);
        }

        return date;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
var date = '7/11/20';
var idx = date.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
date = date.substr(0,idx) + '20' + date.substr(idx);
var result = Date.parse(date);​
alert(result);
```

or this version that will test for a YYYY format first.

```
var date = '7/11/2020'; 
var idx = date.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
if(date.substr(idx).length < 4) {
    date = date.substr(0,idx) + '20' + date.substr(idx);
}
var result = Date.parse(date);
alert(new Date(result))​;​
```

Comment: @BrunoLM - I think the assumption is that YY format will always be used. Easy enough to add a test for a YYYY format.

Comment: Well a user could type in YY or YYYY. I am not sure about YYY don't know if that works. I know the first 2 C# can figure out and parse and so can datepicker.